# Create UL with data from a set of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I have a selection of divs with the exact markup below and I want to create an unordered list above those divs that will provide the ground work for a 'tab' system - all without modifying the below markup.

```
    <div id="category_1">
        <h3 class="maintitle">
            <a class="toggle">..</a>
            <a href="#">Cat 1 Title</a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="category_2">
        <h3 class="maintitle">
            <a class="toggle">..</a>
            <a href="#">Cat 2 Title</a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="category_3">
        <h3 class="maintitle">
            <a class="toggle">..</a>
            <a href="#">Cat 3 Title</a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I want to create with jQuery or just pure JS if easy enough:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" rel="category_1">Cat 1 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="category_2">Cat 2 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="category_3">Cat 3 Title</a></li>
    </ul>
```

- The rel would be the ID of the div so I know which tabs to show / hide later on.
- The value of the LI item would be the text of the second anchor within the H3 of the original code.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: You don't have `</a>` in the markup you want to create

Comment: I attempted to clone the divs and strip out the stuff I didn't need but had issues and wasn't very efficient. I was hoping someone could advise on an easier method of achieving this result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting div's to li to create a jquery carousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175739/converting-divs-to-li-to-create-a-jquery-carousel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var $uls = $('<ul/>');
    $('[id^=category]').each(function () { // Provide a container that hold the div as context.

       var anch = $(this).find('h3 a').eq(1).clone(); //clone your anchor the second one in h3
        anch[0].rel = this.id; // set the rel with the id
        $('<li/>').append(anch).appendTo($uls); // append to temp ul

    });
    $('body').append($uls); // Append anywhere you want

});
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/XmarF/

If you don't want to clone your anchor then you can try this too..

```
$(function () {
    var $uls = $('<ul/>');
    $('[id^=category]').each(function () {
       $('<li/>').append($('<a/>', {
            href: '#',
            rel: this.id,
            text: $(this).find('h3 a').eq(1).text()
        })).appendTo($uls);
    });
    $('body').append($uls);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('div[id^="category_"]').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var title = $(this).children('h3').find('a').eq(1).text();
    var listItem = $("<li><a href='#'></a></li>");
    listItem.find('a').attr('rel',id).text(title);
    $('ul').append(listItem);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsae5/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery's [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method. It will replace a current HTML with one you desire. So if your divs were in a wrapper with a name you could do something like:

```
$("#wrapperID > div").each(function(i) {
    var li = $("<li />").html($(this).html());
    $(this).replaceWith(li);
});
var ul = $("<ul />", { id: 'wrapperID ' }).html($("#wrapperID ").html());
$("#wrapperID ").replaceWith(ul);
```

|OR| if you're looking to convert to that exact markup, again I assume all divs in some type of wrapper with ID (for simplicity):

```
$("#wrapperID > div").each(function(i) {
    var li = $("<li />"),
        a = $("<a />", { href: "#", rel: $(this).prop("id"), text: $(this).find("a").last().text() }).appendTo(li);
    $(this).replaceWith(li);
});
var ul = $("<ul />", { id: 'wrapperID ' }).html($("#wrapperID ").html());
$("#wrapperID ").replaceWith(ul);
```

## See Working Example Here

Answer (score 0):

With no jQuery, this will work in IE8 and up.

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=category_]");
var ul = divs[0].parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("ul"), divs[0]);

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    ul.appendChild(document.createElement("li"))
      .appendChild(divs[i].querySelector("a[href='#']").cloneNode(true))
      .rel = divs[i].id
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/ENvNq/1/

---

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').prepend($("<ul class='menu'>"));

$('div a[href]').each(function () {
    var el = $(this).clone().attr('rel', $(this).closest('div').attr('id'))
    el = $('<li></li>').append(el);
    $('ul.menu').append(el);
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/ht3Y7/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three lines (and maybe less):

```
var html='';
$('div[id^="category"]').each(function () {html += '<li>' + $(this).find('a.toggle').next().text() + '</li>';});
$('#category_1').before('<ul>'+html);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8PjMc/)**